# Select top 1 result from subquery in linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Here  is my sql query as follow

```
select enq_Id,enq_FromName,
       enq_EmailId,
       enq_Phone,
       enq_Subject,
       enq_Message,
       enq_EnquiryBy,
       enq_Mode,
       enq_Date,
       ProductId,
       (select top 1 image_name 
        from tblProductImage as i 
        where i.product_id=p.product_Id) as imageName,
       p.product_Name,
       p.product_code    
 from tblEnquiry as e 
 inner join tblProduct as p ON e.ProductId=p.product_Id
 where ProductId is not null
```

And I try to convert this sql statement into linq as follow

```
var result = from e in db.tblEnquiries
             join d in db.tblProducts 
                  on e.ProductId equals d.product_Id                     
             where e.ProductId != null
             orderby e.enq_Date descending
             select new {
                e.enq_Id,
                e.enq_FromName,
                e.enq_EmailId,
                e.enq_Phone,
                e.enq_Subject,
                e.enq_Message,
                e.enq_EnquiryBy,
                e.enq_Mode,
                e.enq_Date,
                d.product_Id,
                d.product_Name,
                imageName = (from soh in db.tblProductImages
                             where soh.product_id == e.ProductId
                             select new { soh.image_name }).Take(1) 
             };
```

But problem its giving me `imageName` in a nested list but i want that `imageName` just as a string .

I also check by using quick watch and in following image you can see that `imageName`  appearing in inner list .

[image: here can be check quick watch result]

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Instead of `Take(1)` which returns sequence `IEnumerable<string>`, use `FirstOrDefault()` which returns single string value (or null if there is no results). Also don't create anonymous type for subquery result:

```
imageName = (from soh in db.tblProductImages
             where soh.product_id == e.ProductId
             select soh.image_name).FirstOrDefault()
```

BTW `FirstOrDefault()` generates `TOP(1)` SQL.

Comment: still its shows in grid view column  { image_name = f55c1573_a658_420e_9d33_2a8d997bbd51.jpg } instead of f55c1573_a658_420e_9d33_2a8d997bbd51.jpg . I directly given that result to data source to gridview

Comment: @rahularyansharma please see small update - that was because you created anonymous type for subquery result: `new { soh.image_name }`. You should simply return string value.

Comment: please do one more thing for me is it possible to edit my question title as right now its not look like general and may be some other not get help just by seeing the title .

Comment: @rahularyansharma sure, no problem. Btw is it Linq to SQL or EF?

Comment: @rahularyansharma I believe now question is nicely formatted :)

Comment: Has other method without be FirstOrDefault(). Any where method be directly in linq expression?